# How to see which quota template is applied to a SharePoint 2013 site collection through PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

How do I use PowerShell to tell me which quota template is being applied to a specific site collection in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I used below Powershell to report on the SharePoint Site Collection Quotas in use on all sites.

Results I got:

[image]

`Quota Name` shows the quota template of the site collection.

PowerShell:

```
$templates = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.quotatemplates
$tFound = $false 
Get-SPSite -Limit ALL| fl Url, 
    @{n=”Storage Used/1MB”;e={[int]($_.Usage.Storage/1MB)}},
    @{n=”Storage Available Warning/1MB”; e={[int](($_.Quota).StorageWarningLevel/1MB)}},
    @{n=”Storage Available Maximum/1MB”; e={[int](($_.Quota).StorageMaximumLevel/1MB)}},
    @{n=”Sandboxed Resource Points Warning”;e={[int](($_.Quota).UserCodeWarningLevel)}},
    @{n=”Sandboxed Resource Points Maximum”;e={[int](($_.Quota).UserCodeMaximumLevel)}},
    @{n=”Quota Name”; e={ 
        foreach($qt in $templates)
            {
                if($qt.QuotaId -eq [int](($_.Quota).QuotaID))
                {
                    $qt.Name; 
                    $tFound = $true
            }
        } 
        if($tFound -eq $false)
        {
             “No Template Applied”
        }
      $tFound=$false;
   }
} >> c:\PSoutput.txt
```

The report will be saved to c:\PSoutput.txt.